# Convert TCP StreamReader/StreamWriter to SSLStream

Tags: c#, ssl, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
public class ServerClient
{
    public  TcpClient tcp;
    public StreamReader streamReader;
    public StreamWriter streamWriter;
    public int accountId;
    public int connectionId;
    public ServerClient(TcpClient clientSocket)
    {
        tcp = clientSocket;
        streamReader = new StreamReader(tcp.GetStream(), false);
        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(tcp.GetStream());
        clientSocket.NoDelay = true;
    }
}
```

Here is how i am listening for data, this is called in a while loop:

```
// Check for message from Client.
NetworkStream s = c.tcp.GetStream();
if (s.DataAvailable)
{
    string data = c.streamReader.ReadLine();

    if (data != null)
    {
        if (ValidateJSON(data))
        {
            OnIncomingData(c, data);
        }                            
    }

}
//continue;
```

Here is how i check if the client is still connected:

```
private bool IsConnected(TcpClient c)
{
    try
    {
        if (c != null && c.Client != null && c.Client.Connected)
        {
            if (c.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
            {
                return !(c.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.Peek) == 0);
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is how i send data into the stream:

```
string JSonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SendData);

c.streamWriter.WriteLine(JSonData);
c.streamWriter.Flush();
```

Here is my client how it listens for message:

```
public void ConnectToWorldServer()
{
    if (socketReady)
    {
        return;
    }
    //Default host and port values;
    string host = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 8080;

    //ClientLoginServer ClientLoginServer = new ClientLoginServer();


    try
    {

        socket = new TcpClient(host, port);
        stream = socket.GetStream();
        socket.NoDelay = true;
        writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        socketReady = true;
        //Preserve the connection to worldserver thrue scenes
        UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(worldserverConnection);
        });

        // Start listening for connections.
        while (true)
        {
            keepReading = true;

            while (keepReading)
            {
                keepReading = true;
                if (socketReady)
                {
                    if (stream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        string data = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
                            {
                                OnIncomingData(data);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Socket error : " + e.Message);
    }

}
```

I have red about SSL Stream. Here is what i have found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx

I have several questions:

1. Do i need to buy an SSL certificate like a certificate for a website ?
2. Can i generate a self-signed SSL certificate? If so and it's needed can you show me any reference of how to achieve that ?
3. Is it possible to attach this SSL Stream to my StreamReader/StreamWriter ? Is it even needed or i have to remake the whole connection/communication thing?
4. When SSLStream is created the whole communication between the server and the client will be encrypted so anybody can't stay in between and listen/understand what they are communicating ?
5. If i have to attach a certificate file to the client so it may establish a successful SSL connection to the server and then send that client to all the people which have to use that client, doesn't that compromise the security of the SSL connection as i am sending them the certificate as well ?

This is all i wanted to ask. The best thing you can do to help me with your answer is if possible please put the code changes i have to apply in order to make that StreamReader/StreamWriter work over encrypted SSL.

Comment: To me, `try .. catch ... return false` is a _very_ strange way of doing "exception handling".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. you need a certificate; `makecert` would work, but it won't be trusted by default, so you'd either need to supply a custom `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` to the consumer, or use a trusted cert; [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) might be useful there
2. [`makecert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`New-SelfSignedCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate)
3. the `SslStream` would need to go *between* the `NetworkStream` and the `StreamReader`; frankly, it isn't clear to make that `StreamReader` give you much here - you could do everything here with just the `Streaam` API; so instead of `WriteLine`, you'd encode manually and then `Write` the encoded buffer; but - there's no reason that you *can't* just whack `SslStream` in the middle of the two
4. yes
5. only the server needs the certificate (and in particular, only the server needs the private key of the certificate); there *is* something related called "client certificates" used for authenticating the *client*, but that is a related but different topic

As an example ripped from SE.Redis and mangled beyond legibility; SE.Redis *optionally* encrypts, and is basically:

```
Stream stream = // connect (get a NetworkStream)
if (config.Ssl) {
    var ssl = new SslStream(stream, ... cert check callbacks, etc ...);
    ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(expectedHost, allowedSslProtocols);
    stream = ssl;
}
```

so it you had something like that, you'd just make sure you attached any `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` *after* you've wrapped the `NetworkStream` in `SslStream`. But again: I *really* think you could remove `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` here without much inconvenience.

Comment: Can you show me how can i wrap NetworkStream in SslStream ? So you think there is no need of NetwrokStream. It is better to use only SslStream right ?

Comment: @TonyStark "Can you show me how can i wrap NetworkStream in SslStream" - hit refresh :)

Comment: @TonyStark "So you think there is no need of NetwrokStream" - I didn't say that at all - `NetworkStream` is a key component to using `SslStream`, since `SslStream` wants a `Stream`, and `NetworkStream` makes a `Socket` look like a `Stream`

Comment: Thank you @Marc Gravel . It's not getting very clear to me. I have never used a Ssl Steam. If i remove `StreamReader/StreamWritter` how am i going to send and read messages from the stream ?

Comment: @TonyStark `stream.Read(...)` and `stream.Write(...)` - but; meh... your existing `StreamReader` / `StreamWriter` code should be fine... maybe just leave that part alone if you're not familiar with that

Comment: Can you show me please how to convert that `NetworkStream` to `SslStream` and then after sending a message what will be the code to read that encrypted message ? I believe i have to modify both server and client to work with encrypted stream.

Comment: If possible i would like to have better example for the server and the client. I am really confused of how it should look like. Thank you once again for assisting on this.

Comment: @TonyStark I already *have* given an example of wrapping the stream; and yes, you need to modify both client and server - the server part needs to call `AuthenticateAsServer` in the wrapping code, rather than `AuthenticateAsClient`, but... that's about it

Comment: Can you modify please your answer with example for the server and the client ?

Comment: @TonyStark it is very hard to write brief examples of SSL-enabled network client + server code; I will refer you to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx) instead; there's an example on that page with client and server

Comment: In the examples there they are not using any `NetworkStream` as i can see. Also where are they attaching the SSL i have to buy ?

Comment: @TonyStark look for `client.GetStream()` in the example - the same method that you are using - that **is** a `NetworkStream`; as for the cert: in the example, they are loading it from a file: look for `serverCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificate);`

Comment: Okey but i do not understand something else. Let's say i send the client application to a person. Sending this application means to send him the certificate as well so he may establish a connection. If i send this certificate away isn't it compromising the security of the ssl connection ?

Comment: @TonyStark that's not how SSL (TLS) works; the client doesn't need the cert in advance, and the many folks who have designed TLS have figured out complex ways to make it work very securely. The client receives the **public key** (which is fine to share) as part of the handshake. The full details of how the PKI works here would take literally hours to explain. The client does not need the private key and you do not need to distribute the certificate manually to the client *at all*

Comment: @TonyStark the only relevant question here is: does the client accept the certificate? i.e. does the client trust that the server is what it claims to be? By default, this is done by having a CA-rooted certificate issued (indirectly) from a CA that the client machine trusts. However, the client can also choose to ignore all errors (accept any certificate), or check the "thumbprint" of the cert manually; for example, you could create your own private CA and have the cert callback say "was it issued via my private CA?" - just by checking the thumbprint.

Comment: So i'm not attaching anything to the client? The clients tryes to establish a connection to the server and receives from the server back what is needed to establish a secure SSL connection, correct ?

Comment: @TonyStark when the client calls `AuthenticateAsClient`, it starts a handshake with the server code that *basically* says "give me the public half of your certificate"; the server code at this time is calling `AuthenticateAsServer`, so that is entirely expected, and the server gives the public part of the certificate; IIRC, if the client accepts the certificate as OK, the client then generates it's own secret key to use for the *actual* encryption, **encrypts that secret with the public key**, and sends the encrypted secret back to the server; *only* the server with the...

Comment: ...private key of the original certificate can decrypt that. I've simplified, but that's *basically* what happens, from a very simplified perspective. The details are ... complex.

Comment: @TonyStark it is actually exactly the same as when you connect to your bank, or Amazon, or this website. You didn't need anything on your computer in advance, and you don't have the private key for stackoverflow.com ... or at least I hope you don't :)

Comment: I got you perfectly. Thank you very much for the whole explanation of how `SslSteam` will work. I'll do my best to implement it. Thank you once again!

Comment: @TonyStark if you're thinking "wow, this sounds complex" - then that's great: that means you understood perfectly. It *is* complex :)

Comment: Just one more thing. To create a certificate can i use https://certbot.eff.org and if so should i mark `Apache`,`nginx` or should i mark anything of the above because actually i'm not using them. I'm using a custom C# application ? What do you think ?

Comment: Yes it's complex but i got the basic idea of how it "works".

Comment: @TonyStark I don't know anything about certbot, sorry. The mention of apache, nginx etc is more about automatically configuring web-servers, but: you don't have a web-server: you just want a cert.